# windows automatic software updates

Tags: .net, deployment, updates

What are some good solutions for handling automatic web based software updates for windows forms projects? I am aware of microsoft one-click, but am not interested in it at this time.

Comment: Can you share why ClickOnce won't work for you? The tool is good enough that you'll have a hard time finding anything that competes with it

Answer (score 15):

ClickOnce is good for cookie cutter stuff, but has some limitations around security (i.e. can't create a desktop icon, no access to COM, etc)

Assuming you are using MSI to install your application.  Use WIX (http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to create a patch (.msp).  You will want to look into Least Privileged User Account (LUA) Patching for Vista as UAC will screw you if you don't.

Then your application does the follows:

1. Check for a new version via HTTP
2. Download the MSP (be careful of  where you DL it to in Vista because of UAC)
3. Start a Shim exe that
4. waits for your app to close
5. launches the msp (in non-interactive mode)
6. restarts your app

This can all happen automatically behind the scenes with zero user interaction on both XP and Vista.

A good place to start with this, and with WIX in general is:

http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/index.php
(Lesson 4 is on Updates)

Comment: not without hacking you can't (If the app is uninstalled, it's not removed)

Answer (score 5):

Not to get too spammy, but our company offers an automatic updating solution. It comes in 3 parts:

- The [open source wyUpdate](http://wyday.com/wyupdate/), which is an updater written in C#
- The [free AutomaticUpdater control](http://wyday.com/wybuild/help/automatic-updates/)
- [wyBuild is used to build patches](http://wyday.com/wybuild/) and manage your versions

wyUpdate handles all of the Vista/Windows 7 UAC problems and all the file permission problems that inevitably pop up when you're trying to update complex software.

Answer (score 3):

We wrote our own at one time... That wasn't a good idea. In many cases you can use ClickOnce. We actually use a product called [AutoUpdate+](http://AutoUpdatePlus.com) which we can recommend. Its particularly special feature is that it can avoid UAC popup issues.

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on how complex of an update process is needed.

I have had a few clients with simple needs where we created our own process setup that handled it, in about 3 hours of development we have a fully working solution that met all of their needs.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft one-click? Do you mean ClickOnce? Click once for win form is very nice. Deployement is fast and all the update process is handled by itself.

Answer (score 0):

but [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) is the best you can have and you can select if users need to download the new version, use the old ones, go back versions, etc...

you can always built your own solution, check the version number of a XML setting file in some web address, if it is newer than the current one, alter user to download the new version for example...

Answer (score 0):

I've also heard it called clicktwice :+>
The WIX solution is more what I was interested in. Are there any sample applications (with source) for using this technique?

Comment: Building a system like this is not a small undertaking.  I have done it, but never found a comprehensive tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an open-source solution I wrote to address specific needs we had for WinForms and WPF apps. The general idea is to have the greatest flexibility, at the lowest overhead possible.

So, **integration** is super-easy, and the library does pretty much everything for you, including synchronizing operations. It is also **highly flexible**, and lets you determine what tasks to execute and on what conditions - you make the rules (or use some that are there already). Last by not least is the support for **any updates source** (web, BitTorrent, etc) and any **feed format** - whatever is not implemented you can just write for yourself.

Cold updates (requiring an application restart) is also supported, and done automatically unless "hot-swap" is specified for the task.

This boild down to one DLL, less than 70kb in size.

More details at http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/

Code is at http://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate (Licensed under the Apache 2.0 license)